# The application Keyboard input Methods has closed unexpectedly

Tags: keyboard, input-method

I get this message: **"The application Keyboard input Methods has closed unexpectedly"** immediately After I log in. It has been happening more recently. Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you open up System Settings > Language Support and check the settings there. Then click the "Apply System-Wide" button (even if you did not change anything). I did this in both the "Language" and "Regional Formats" tabs and it fixed this issue for me (at least it has been fine for the past 24hrs since I did this).

Comment: I'd be interested to know why that would work...

Answer (score 0):

You can restart it from a terminal window by running the command

```
ibus-daemon -dr
```

But to me it sounds like you should report it as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+filebug).

Comment: Could anyone please tell me why this I get this error? Thanks

Comment: @AaKavous: I can't, I'm afraid. Happens to me too occationally, but not very often. Probably a bug report is a better place to spot the reason why it happens.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar, since I ran the "ibus-daemon -dr" command as you said this has not happened so-far. I will report back should it recourse. Thanks again

Comment: I am getting the same error as before and "ibus-daemon -dr" has not resolved the problem. If anyone has a solution please post your solution. Thanks